# Changes apply on the second tap

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` and I am trying to make it with multiple selections so I can perform an action to all items selected.
I have to mention that in the fragment that holds one item I have a radio button(`radioButton`), some text, and a button(`joinBtn`).

What I want to do is that when I click the item, the radio button will become checked, and the button will become visible and enabled.

My class `Group` has a `private boolean clicked = false` by default.

In the `ViewHolder` I have the method `bind` :

```
public void bind(Group group) {
            this.group = group;
            mTitleTextView.setText(group.getName());
            if(group.isClicked())
                radioButton.setChecked(true);
            else
                radioButton.setChecked(false);
        }
```

And in the `onClick` method i have the actions I want to perform:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (joinBtn.isShown()) {
                joinBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                joinBtn.setEnabled(false);
                group.setClicked(false);
            }
            else{
                joinBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                joinBtn.setEnabled(true);
                group.setClicked(true);
            }
        }
```

My problem is the behaviour I get:
1st tap: radio button gets checked.
2nd tap: joinBtn appears.
3rd tap: radio button gets unchecked.
4th tap: joinBtn disappears.

How can I make the actions from 1st and 2nd tap to happen in one tap? The same for 3rd and 4th?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `notifyItemChanged(int position)` on the adapter instance after your `onClick()` logic. Pass the index of the item as the param.

The UI may not update by itself, but this function should refresh it.

Comment: dosen't work, it resets what I do in the onClick and only does what is in bind

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a flag which will change on group click

```
boolean isChecked = false ;


public void bind(Group group) {
            this.group = group;
            mTitleTextView.setText(group.getName());

            if(isChecked)
                isChecked = false;
                radioButton.setChecked(false);
            else
                isChecked = true;
                radioButton.setChecked(true);
        }
```

and then

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (isChecked) {
                joinBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                joinBtn.setEnabled(false);
                group.setClicked(false);
            }
            else{
                joinBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                joinBtn.setEnabled(true);
                group.setClicked(true);
            }
        }
```

Comment: still doesn't work right.. the only way i got a bit closer to what I want is by putting all my conditions in the `bind` method, and calling `bind` in `onClick`, but still it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was because of the radio button. The first thing I did was to use a `ImageView` instead of the radio button. In that `ImageView` I used (when needed) one of two pictures: selected or unselected.
In the `bind` method all I needed was: `joinBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);` and `radioBtnImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.radio_btn_unselected);`

In the `onClick` method I used:

```
 if (joinBtn.isShown()) {

                joinBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                joinBtn.setClickable(false);
                radioBtnImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.radio_btn_unselected);
            }
            else{

                joinBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                joinBtn.setClickable(true);
                radioBtnImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.radio_btn_selected);
            }
```

This did it for me!